# How do I call functions at a specific rate in embedded C/C++?

Tags: c++, embedded, nvidia-jetson-nano

What is the best practice and an example of how to call functions at a specific rate?  At work I write code in functions that get called at 100ms or 50ms or whatever rate is needed, but I don't know how to do the low level code that makes it possible for me to just call a function at a specific rate.

I am writing my code in c++ on the Jetson-Nano.  I also want to be able to do the same thing for code that runs on my laptop as well (needs to have the same execution speed as the code I'm running on the nano).

In my research I saw different methods using delays and interrupts, but I'm a novice at this so I wanted to make sure that I choose the best approach.  Best meaning, the most professional, efficient, effective, and whatever other good adjectives fit.

Comment: Interrupts are a great way to run code at a set interval. This is a widly used pracitce in embedded systems. Using delays (like sleep() in arduino for example) "block" your code execution, which may be undesirable in some applications

Comment: Jetson Nano is hardly typical of embedded systems - presumably it is running some sort of OS?  I believe Ubuntu Linux as shipped?  The answer in that case will be very different that if you were running bare-metal or an RTOS.  You say "_At work I write code in functions that get called at 100ms or 50ms_" without explaining how you arrange that, or what system "at work" code runs on (i.e. it is not useful information).  Given that the board runs Linux, you might use the same technique.  At its simplest, a continuous loop, polling a clock and invoking functions when it is time.

Comment: @Clifford sorry I didn't notice this earlier.  So yes the nano has an OS, it's kind of like using the raspberry pi, but it has a GPU, which is the selling point.  At work the low level code and logic that handles the different scheduled rates is abstracted from me.  I tried to find it but couldn't.  To be continued in next comment...

Comment: @Clifford When I write a function such as "MyFunction_100ms()", all I have to do is declare it in the middleware and add it to a function such as "Task_100ms()" like "Task_100ms(){ MyFunction_100ms(); }", where every function call put into that task function gets executed at the desired rate.  The scheduler "Task_100ms()" function is abstracted away and I couldn't see exactly how they do it.

Comment: @ee-4-me I'll definitely look into interrupts.  I know for certain that I don't want to use delays.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the Jetson Nano runs [Jetson Linux](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-linux) the question is not really specific to embedded systems.

There is no "one method" used in embedded systems in any event. A simple generic solution is simply to have a continuous loop, that invokes functions when it is time to do so.  You might have a table of functions and periods and implement a simple scheduler:

```cpp
struct
{
    void (*periodic_function)(void) ;
    int period_ms ;
    int last_exec_time ;
} tasks[] =
{
    {task1, 50, 0 },
    {task2, 100, 0 },
    {task3, 10, 0 }
} ;

constexpr std::size_t TASK_COUNT = sizeof(tasks)/sizeof(*tasks) ;

for(;;)
{
    int now_ms = clock_ms() ;
    for( int t = 0; t < TASK_COUNT; t++ )
    {
        if( now - tasks[t].last_exec_time >= tasks[t].period_ms )
        {
            tasks[t].last_exec_time = now ;
            tasks[t].periodic_function() ; 
        }
    }

    sleep(1) ;
}
```

Where `clock_ms` might be implemented in various ways, e.g:

```cpp
#include time.h
int clock_ms()
{
    return std::clock() / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000 ) ;
}
```

Alternatively you could simply create separate [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pthreads) for each period, crudely:

```c
void periodicThread50ms()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        periodic_function_50ms() ;
        sleep( 50 ) ;
    }
}
```

A direct solution for periodic functions given a POSIX API would be to use a [POSIX timer](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) with `SIGEV_THREAD` to trigger run-to-completion functions periodically. e.g:

```cpp
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handler50ms(union sigval sv) 
{
    ...
}

void handler75ms(union sigval sv) 
{
    ...
}


int main()
{
    timer_t timerid50ms = {0} ;
    sigevent event50ms = {0} ;
    event50ms.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD ;
    event50ms.sigev_notify_function = handler50ms ;
    timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &event50ms, &timerid50ms) ;

    itimerspec period50ms = {0} ;
    period50ms.it_value.tv_nsec = 50000000 ;
    period50ms.it_interval.tv_nsec = period50ms.it_value.tv_nsec ;
    timer_settime( timerid50ms, 0, &period50ms, nullptr ) ; 

    timer_t timerid75ms = {0} ;
    sigevent event75ms = {0} ;
    event75ms.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD ;
    event75ms.sigev_notify_function = handler75ms ;
    timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &event75ms, &timerid75ms) ;

    itimerspec period75ms = {0} ;
    period75ms.it_value.tv_nsec = 75000000 ;
    period75ms.it_interval.tv_nsec = period75ms.it_value.tv_nsec ;
    timer_settime( timerid75ms, 0, &period75ms, nullptr ) ; 


    for(;;)
    {
        // do other stuff here
        sleep(1) ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

The POSIX timer functionality is flexible, but perhaps somewhat cumbersome.  A wrapper or facade providing just the functionality you require is a good idea.  For example you might define:

```
timer_t startTimer( int period_ms, void (*handler)(sigval), sigval handler_arg )
{
    timer_t timerid = 0 ;
    sigevent event = {0} ;
    event.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD ;
    event.sigev_notify_function = handler ;
    event.sigev_value = handler_arg ;
    timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &event, &timerid) ;

    itimerspec period = {0} ;
    time_t seconds = period_ms / 1000 ;
    long nanoseconds = (period_ms % 1000) * 1000000 ;
    period.it_value.tv_sec = seconds ;
    period.it_value.tv_nsec = nanoseconds ;
    period.it_interval.tv_sec = seconds ;
    period.it_interval.tv_nsec = nanoseconds ;
    timer_settime( timerid, 0, &period, nullptr ) ; 

    return timerid ;
}
```

Then the previous example `main()` would look like:

```
int main()
{
    sigval arg ;
    
    arg.sival_int = 50 ;
    startTimer( 50, handler50ms, arg ) ;
    
    arg.sival_int = 75 ;
    startTimer( 75, handler75ms, arg ) ;

    for(;;)
    {
        // do other stuff here
        sleep(1) ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

The `handler_arg` parameter is passed to the timer handler and may be used to pass information to the handler.  Because it is a union with a pointer value, you can pass anything your application needs.

`startTimer()` returns the timer ID allowing you to manipulate the timer.  For example you might want to stop a timer:

```
int stopTimer( timer_t timer_id )
{
    return timer_delete( timer_id ) ;
}
```

Comment: @pmacfarlane : Probably not - illustrative only, and typed in a hurry not actual tested code.  Will check.

Comment: @pmacfarlane : fixed, real code, complete, tested.

Comment: @Clifford thank you for the example!  And also for clarifying the scope of the question, I'll try to fix that.  So it seems like the first approach has sequential execution of the code, so things happen in order.  And the second approach using the threads means I can execute multiple pieces of code in parallel.  You did use the term scheduler to describe the first approach, and I do like the idea of a scheduler for different tasks if they can be done at different rates to manage resources.  Can the separate thread approach also be viewed as a way to "schedule" functions?

Comment: @crose72 multi threading relies on the operating system scheduler.  In Linux the normal scheduler is a time-slice scheduler where the task priority affects how much CPU time a thread gets, but not when it gets it (i.e. not real-time). There is a RT_PREMPT scheduler where the highest priority "ready" thread runs until it either blocks/yields or is itself pre-empted.  It is intended to provide more deterministic response, but it does not make Linux a true RTOS. Using the OS scheduler is likely in either case to be better than the "big-loop".

Comment: Correction : PREEMPT_RT.  https://orenbell.com/setting-up-realtime-kernel-on-jetson/

Comment: forgive me if my questions seem naive, I'm not very experienced with this particular area and I'm trying to understand and figure out the best approach.  I think the main result we want is deterministic behavior and to be able to predictably and accurately perform time dependent operations (filters, timers, etc).  I'm going to look at that PREEMPT_RT link you included.  Is the OS scheduler you mention in the last line of your comment the same as the PREEMPT_RT approach?  And is the "big-loop" approach just throwing everything into "main" or... tbc

Comment: continued from ^ ... or your first example where the tasks are defined in the structure or using the POSIX timer?

Comment: "big loop" refers to my first example.  It was in answer to your question where you asked about "embedded" without qualification regarding the platform or OS.  Hardly applicable in your case, included for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

It somewhat depends on the complexity of the project you're working on. If there are only a few functions you're calling, and they're all relatively quick to run (compared to the frequency you're calling them at), then interrupts are a clean, simple way to accomplish this.

If your project is more complex — lots of tasks with varying priority, say, then you'd be better off using an [RTOS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) (real-time operating system). Don't be put off by the word "operating system", thinking something like Linux or Windows. An RTOS is (generally) a very tiny, simple kernel to handle sharing processor time between tasks and guaranteeing consistent timing.

Comment: The platform mentioned is Jetson-Nano - The SDK _is_ Linux.  https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetpack

Comment: @mister-sir So the project itself will be quite complex, controlling a drone and doing inference with a DNN or transfer / attention model, and the code will interface with the flight controller to control the drone, and the camera. I do want to be able to use filtering and other techniques that depend on discreet time.  We will be leveraging CUDA so that the ML stuff can be done on the GPU exclusively.  Is a RTOS relatively simple to implement?

Comment: @crose72 Is this a vision-based application? If so, you probably want to use Nvidia's DeepStream stuff. It's optimised for the Jetson.

Comment: @crose72 : By using an RTOS, you would loose all the hardware support for the platform and have to build all that yourself as well as a great deal of third party support.  Much of it is likely to be Nvidia proprietary so only available via Jetpack.  The more complex the platform, the more tied in to the vendors chosen ecosystem you end up.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Yes, if a squirrel pops up in the frame then locate it in the frame and command the drone to follow it.

Comment: @Clifford okay so that seems like something I don't want to do for this particular project.  We chose the nano for its GPU, but want to keep the workflow and setup as simple as possible.

Comment: The DeepStream SDK gives you object detection and tracking etc. You might need to train it to recognise squirrels though! It's all based on gstreamer, which is a curse and a blessing. There's a lot to it, but it does a lot of the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this concept?  Basically just using an interrupt with a mutex to avoid concurrent function calls.

Currently I'm compiling this code in WSL2 and on Ubuntu-18.04 on my jetson nano and it does compile and run on both, I only have it print the elapsed time to the console though.  I have a more "advanced" implementation of it on my github where I refactored to make it fit the architecture of my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <time.h>
#include <mutex>

bool stopProgram = false;
std::mutex mutex;
long long startTimeMs; // Variable to store the start time in milliseconds


// Function to handle timer interrupt at 40Hz
void timerHandler(int sig, siginfo_t* si, void* uc)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    // Get the current timestamp in milliseconds
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto timestamp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();

    // Calculate the elapsed time since the start of the program
    long long elapsedTimeMs = timestamp - startTimeMs;

    // Print the elapsed time and the function name
    std::cout << "Elapsed Time: " << elapsedTimeMs << "\n";
}

// Function to handle signal to stop the program
void stopHandler(int sig)
{
    stopProgram = true;
}

int main()
{
    // Set up the signal handler for stopping the program
    struct sigaction sa_stop;
    sa_stop.sa_handler = stopHandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa_stop.sa_mask);
    sa_stop.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa_stop, nullptr); // Register SIGINT (Ctrl+C) handler

    // Set up the signal handler for the timer
    struct sigaction sa_timer;
    sa_timer.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa_timer.sa_sigaction = timerHandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa_timer.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGRTMIN, &sa_timer, nullptr);

    // Create and set up the timer
    timer_t timerID;
    struct sigevent sev;
    struct itimerspec its;

    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = SIGRTMIN;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerID;

    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &timerID);

    its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 1000000000 / 40; // nanoseconds per period for 40Hz
    its.it_value = its.it_interval;


    // Get the start time
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    startTimeMs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();

    timer_settime(timerID, 0, &its, nullptr);

    // Run the program until the stop condition is true
    while (!stopProgram)
    {
        // Lock the mutex to prevent concurrent execution
        //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

        // Your main program logic here
        // ...
    }

    // Delete the timer
    timer_delete(timerID);

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the makefile to make your life easier if you want to try it out :)

```
CXX := g++
# Compiler flags
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
# Linker flags
LDFLAGS := -lrt
# Source files
SRCS := main.cpp
# Object files
OBJS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
# Output executable name
EXEC := main

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(EXEC) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```